# How to use Anonymous Closure in Swift?

Tags: swift, closures

A closure function :

```
func makeIncrementer(externNumber:Int) -> (Int -> Int) {
    func addOne(number: Int) -> Int {
        return externNumber + number
    }
    return addOne
}
```

I want to use Anonymous Closure to achieve it, so I write this :

```
func my_makeIncrementer(externNumber:Int) -> (Int -> Int) {
    return {
        (number:Int)-> Int {  // Error : cannot create a single-element tuple with an element label ;
        return externNumber + number ;
        } ;
    }
}
```

You can see, Xcode throw a error

> Error : cannot create a single-element tuple with an element label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should re-look up the syntax [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html):

```
func my_makeIncrementer(externNumber:Int) -> (Int -> Int) {
    return {
        (number:Int)-> Int in

        return externNumber + number
    }
}
```